# XAML GridView Remove space between items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview

I have this GridView,

[image]

And want to remove spaces between items, I Try setting Marging and Padding to 0 as this:

```
           <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=AprehenderPage,Path=DataContext.LecturasCorrectas}"
                  Margin="0"
                  Padding="0">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="35" 
                          Margin="0" 
                          Padding="0">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Imagen}"
                               Margin="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

But this does nothing.

How Can I do to remove those spaces?

or

What other control must I use?

Answer (score 3):

It *looks* like you might be using UWP rather than WPF as I don't think WPF [GridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx) has an ItemsSource. If that's the case, then your margin is probably from GridViewItem:

GridViewItem (the container object) has Margin according to MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299127.aspx

So you'll need to restyle the item like so:

```
    <Style x:Key="MyItem" TargetType="GridViewItem">
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
      <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
```

And have a setter on your gridview for container style:

```
<Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyItem}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try auto height.

```
<Grid Height="Auto" ...
```

Also you can have negative margins if need be

and margins like..

```
Margin ="-value"
```

Comment: Where I must place it ?  At item template ?  or at grid definition ?

Comment: updated my answer try with auto height within template then work it out accordingly

Comment: Nothing, negative margins does nothing as I need, it generates a strange Overlaying between Items.